# Drag and drop UIButton and connect them with a line iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, drag-and-drop

i want to drag and drop my UIButton from one place to another, and from certain point i want to connect them with another button by line. like when we connect our button action with interface builder.

is there any sample code or document for this ?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "connect them with another button" ?

Comment: okay, i want to use diagonal line .

Comment: like there are 2 buttons b1 and b2 and i want to connect b1 and b2 then touch b1 and move to b2 like, b1----------------------b2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this link for reference
http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter11.html

You can also check the Cocoa Drawing tutorials http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: yes i see it , but i think it just draw a line but i want drag effect too.

Comment: thanks , but i want to connect this lines with two buttons and if i drag this buttons then line should be drag accordingly it.

Comment: the code which is present in this link has a method called touchesmoved. You can get the drag effect from that. check this  http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6984/discussion-between-pjr-and-sharanya)

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to move the buttons center point based on TouchesMoved. Then you will have to draw a line - depending on what you want there are a number of ways to achieve that.